# Counterexample for floor function: $\lfloor x+y \rfloor \geq \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am told that there is absolutely a counter-example for this floor function
 $$\lfloor x+y \rfloor \geq \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor $$

With the domain of the discourse being all real numbers. I have tried many different examples but I simply cannot figure anything out. If anyone could provide some help I would be much obliged.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

There cannot be counterexample (if you wrote the inequality exactly), since
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\lfloor {x + y} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\{ x \right\} + \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor  + \left\{ y \right\}} \right\rfloor  =   \cr 
  &  = \left\lfloor {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor } \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\left\{ x \right\} + \left\{ y \right\}} \right\rfloor  =   \cr 
  &  = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\left\{ x \right\} + \left\{ y \right\}} \right\rfloor  \ge \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor  \cr} 
$$

and by definition of the fractional part
$$
0 \le \left\{ x \right\} < 1
$$